# Peripherals needed to run Tiny BASIC interactively on an Intel 8080

Tags: hardware, basic, 8080

I have an Intel 8080 core and would like to build the minimal computer system around it to run Tiny BASIC interactively. I am building this computer on an FPGA, so I am not asking about actual components, rather, the connection of the peripherals in terms of ports or memory mapped addresses.

An ideal answer to my question would consist of a link to a Tiny BASIC binary ready to be loaded on an Intel 8080, together with memory layout information (e.g. "put the binary at RAM starting at 0x0000 with size at least 4 K"), initialization ("reset PC to 0x0100 to start"), and IO (e.g. "if a byte is written to port 0x01, show it as ASCII to the user. If a byte is read from port 0x02, return 1 if a new input byte is ready, 0 otherwise. If a byte is read from port 0x69, return the next input byte", or "interrupt with `RST 3` when a new input byte is available and put it to RAM address 0Ff000").

I should also add that I am looking for a standalone version, not one that requires CP/M. The simpler the peripherals, the better.

Comment: You can emulate the surroundings for a program loaded by and running under CP/M relatively simple, as you most likely only need to load the program at $0100 and set up page zero and a small stub in high memory.  That is naturally assuming that BASIC does not do file access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Tiny BASIC 1 and 2 source code, for exactly the same reason you described (my own 8080-based computer).

[Here is a source code and a binary](https://github.com/omenmicro/alpha/tree/master/sw/BASIC), ready to loaded from 01000h. Serial communication is provided by ACIA MC6850 - see lines 1420 - 1475, routines `outc` and `chkio`. ACIA is accessed via 0DEh (control/status register) and 0DFh (data register).

So: Load it from 1000h, start it with `JMP 01000h`, reading from 0DEh awaits a status byte (bit 2=1 when ACIA is clear to send, bit 1=1 when ACIA has received data), reading from 0DFh reads received data, writing to 0DFh sends data to transmission.

I believe you can appreciate [VHDL implementation of MC6850 for FPGA](https://github.com/datacipy/VHDL/tree/master/acia6850).

*(Feel free to contact me for further details or help with customization for your hardware.)*

Comment: It is standard Intel .HEX format. You can convert it to the plain BIN with some tools, e.g. this one: https://www.asm80.com/tools/index.html#/hex2bin

Comment: I believe there are no data at 0800h. The code should take space 1000h - 17E9h. See the listing here: https://gist.github.com/maly/813858080d3fed142f2554af392ae964

Comment: what assembler can I use to re-assemble your `.a80` file?

Comment: Feel free to use https://www.asm80.com online assembler or use the CLI version https://www.npmjs.com/package/asm80, if you are familiar with the Node.js